# Making more remoting calls than threads by making synchronous methods async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, remoting

I have a bunch of remoting calls that are all synchronous (3rd party library). Most of them take a lot of time so I'm not able to use them more often then about 5 to 10 times per second. This is too slow because I need to call them at least 3000 times every couple of minutes and many more if the services was stopped for some time. There is virtually no CPU work on the client. It gets the data, checks some simple conditions and makes another call that it has to wait for.

What would be the best way to make them async (call them in an async fashion - I guess I need some async wrapper) so that I can make more requests at the same time? Currently It's limited by the number of threads (which is four).

I was thinking about calling them with `Task.Run` but every article I read says it's for CPU bound work and that it uses thread-pool threads. If I get it correctly, with this approach I won't be able to break the thread limit, will I?. So which approach would actually fit best here?

What about `Task.FromResult`? Can I await such methods asynchronously in a greater number than there are threads?

```
public async Task<Data> GetDataTakingLotsOfTime(object id)
{
    var data = remoting.GetData(id);
    return await Task.FromResult(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking about calling them with Task.Run but every article I read says it's for CPU bound work and that it uses thread-pool threads.

Yes, but when you're stuck with a sync API then `Task.Run()` might be your lesser evil, especially on a Client.

Your current version of GetDataTakingLotsOfTime() is not really async. The FromResult() merely helps to suppress the Warning about that.

> What about Task.FromResult? Can I await such methods asynchronously in a greater number than there are threads?

Not clear where your "number of threads" idea comes from but yes, starting a Task method and awaiting it later essentially runs it on the ThreadPool. But Task.Run is clearer in that respect.

Note that that does not depend on the `async` modifier of the method - async is an implementation detail, the caller only cares that it returns a Task.

> Currently It's limited by the number of threads (which is four).

This needs some explaining. I don't get it.

Comment: mhmm... if `Task.Run` is my only option then where do the _true_ async APIs come from? They must be using something else, right? But let's say I create 100 tasks with `Task.Run`, will I be able to fire 100 requests at the same time or will the limit be the number or hardware/cpu threads?

Comment: By the _number of threads_ I meant the number of CPUs - the number the task manager shows.

Comment: 'true' async APIs use async I/O which, preferably, uses I/O completion ports instead of threads. Remoting (i assume you mean that pre-WCF stuff) is too old for Tasks but do look for BeginXXX and EndXXX methods that return IAsyncResult.

Comment: The max number of pool threads on a 64 bit process is in the thousands, but you do want to keep it as low as possible. 100 would be a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing a remote call, and your thread needs to wait idly for the result of the remote call. During this wait your thread could do useful things, like executing other remote calls.

Times when your thread is idly waiting for other processes to finish, like writing to a disk, querying a database or fetching information from the internet are typically situations where you'll see an async function next to a non-async function: `Write` and `WriteAsync`, `Send` and `SendAsync`.

If at the deepest level of your synchronous call you have access to an async version of the call, then your life would be easy. Alas it seems that you don't have such an async version.

Your proposed solution using `Task.Run` has the disadvantage of the overhead in starting a new thread (or running one from the thread pool).

You could lower this overhead by creating a workshop object. In the workshop, a dedicated thread (a worker), or several dedicated threads are waiting at one input point for an order to do something. The threads performs the task and posts the result at the output point.

Users of the workshop have one access point (front office?) where they post the request to do something, and await for the result.

For this I used [System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.BufferBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx). Install Nuget package TPL Dataflow.

You can dedicate your workshop to accept only work to `GetDataTakingLotsOfTime`; I made my workshop generic: I accept every job that implements interface IWork:

```
interface IWork
{
    void DoWork();
}
```

The WorkShop has two `BufferBlocks`: one to input work requests and one to output finished work. The workshop has a thread (or several threads) that wait at the input `BufferBlock` until a job arrives. Does the `Work`, and when finished posts the job to the output `BufferBlock`

```
class WorkShop
{
    public WorkShop()
    {
         this.workRequests = new BufferBlock<IWork>();
         this.finishedWork = new BufferBlock<IWork>();
         this.frontOffice = new FrontOffice(this.workRequests, this.finishedWork);
    }

    private readonly BufferBlock<IWork> workRequests;
    private readonly BufferBlock<IWork> finishedWork;
    private readonly FrontOffice frontOffice;

    public FrontOffice {get{return this.frontOffice;} }

    public async Task StartWorkingAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (await this.workRequests.OutputAvailableAsync(token)
        {   // some work request at the input buffer
            IWork requestedWork = this.workRequests.ReceiveAsync(token);
            requestedWork.DoWork();
            this.FinishedWork.Post(requestedWork);
        }
        // if here: no work expected anymore:
        this.FinishedWork.Complete();
    }

    // function to close the WorkShop
    public async Task CloseShopAsync()
    {
         // signal that no more work is to be expected:
         this.WorkRequests.Complete();
         // await until the worker has finished his last job for the day:
         await this.FinishedWork.Completion();
    }
}
```

TODO: proper reaction on CancellationToken.CancellationRequested
TODO: proper reaction on exceptions thrown by work
TODO: decide whether to use several threads doing the work

FrontOffice has one async function, that accepts work, sends the work to the WorkRequests and awaits for the work to finish:

```
public async Task<IWork> OrderWorkAsync(IWork work, CancellationToken token)
{
    await this.WorkRequests.SendAsync(work, token);
    IWork finishedWork = await this.FinishedWork.ReceivedAsync(token);
    return finishedWork;
}
```

So your process created a WorkShop object and starts one or more threads that will StartWorking.

Whenever any thread (inclusive your main thread) needs some work to be performed in async-await fashion:

- Create An object that holds the input parameters and the DoWork function
- Ask the WorkShop for the FrontOffice
- await OrderWorkAsync

.

```
class InformationGetter : IWork
{
     public int Id {get; set;}                     // the input Id
     public Data FetchedData {get; private set;}   // the result from Remoting.GetData(id);
     public void DoWork()
     {
         this.FetchedData = remoting.GetData(this.Id);
     }
}
```

Finally the Async version of your remote

```
async Task<Data> RemoteGetDataAsync(int id)
{
     // create the job to get the information:
     InformationGetter infoGetter = new InformationGetter() {Id = id};

     // go to the front office of the workshop and order to do the job
     await this.MyWorkShop.FrontOffice.OrderWorkAsync(infoGetter);
     return infoGetter.FetchedData;
}
```

Comment: I was always wondering where the dataflow blocks could be useful. This solution is awsome! I'll get to work ;-)

Comment: Let me know if you manage to get it working with an `Action` or `Function` instead of interface `IWork`; I'm also curious on how you get several threads doing the jobs that are offered at the front office